# How to have only panel slide down up one by one upon click

Tags: jquery

Jquery

```
    jQuery ( function ( $ ) {
  var post = $('div.post');

  post.on('click', function(e){
    toggle();
  });

  function toggle(){
    var panel = $('div.postPanel');
    if (panel.is(":hidden")) {
       panel.slideDown('slow');
   } else {
     panel.slideUp('slow', function () {
        $(this).hide();
     });
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
    <section>
      <div class="post">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vulputate ex posuere, lacinia ex a, tempor diam. Integer porta ante sit amet turpis gravida
      </div>
      <div class="postPanel">
        ac finibus augue feugiat. Mauris ornare ligula a neque venenatis, in sodales dolor vehicula. Duis eget euismod arcu. Aliquam sollicitudin porta ante vitae sollicitudin. Nullam leo erat, tempus vel sodales et, ullamcorper faucibus massa. Morbi lacinia mi vulputate, tincidunt neque nec, aliquam magna. Proin et dictum quam, pulvinar dignissim lacus. Maecenas ligula elit, scelerisque sit amet finibus at, sodales ac ipsum. Vestibulum vulputate bibendum augue eu egestas. Sed nulla felis, blandit at tincidunt nec, tempus eu justo. Nunc hendrerit id risus id tristique. Aenean libero quam, ultricies eget mattis sit amet, scelerisque at ante. Mauris pellentesque varius rutrum. Vivamus turpis justo, commodo sit amet magna in, blandit convallis mauris. Suspendisse potenti.
      </div>

    </section>
   <section>
      <div class="post">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vulputate ex posuere, lacinia ex a, tempor diam. Integer porta ante sit amet turpis gravida
      </div>
      <div class="postPanel">
        ac finibus augue feugiat. Mauris ornare ligula a neque venenatis, in sodales dolor vehicula. Duis eget euismod arcu. Aliquam sollicitudin porta ante vitae sollicitudin. Nullam leo erat, tempus vel sodales et, ullamcorper faucibus massa. Morbi lacinia mi vulputate, tincidunt neque nec, aliquam magna. Proin et dictum quam, pulvinar dignissim lacus. Maecenas ligula elit, scelerisque sit amet finibus at, sodales ac ipsum. Vestibulum vulputate bibendum augue eu egestas. Sed nulla felis, blandit at tincidunt nec, tempus eu justo. Nunc hendrerit id risus id tristique. Aenean libero quam, ultricies eget mattis sit amet, scelerisque at ante. Mauris pellentesque varius rutrum. Vivamus turpis justo, commodo sit amet magna in, blandit convallis mauris. Suspendisse potenti.
      </div>

    </section>
```

I have dynamic generated posts to display in listing. When click on one of the posts, it will show all sliding "postPanel" which is not right. Want each sliding "postPanel" to show when click on each post.

Comment: show your sample html code

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the user clicking on a post to toggle a corresponding panel. We can't really help you without knowing how your posts and panels are arranged. Please provide the relevant HTML.

Comment: @flowstoneknight - add in example html. Yes click on a post to show its panel with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** selector to select the next .postPanel

```
 jQuery ( function ( $ ) {
  var post = $('div.post');

  post.on('click', function(e){
    toggle(this);
  });

  function toggle(elm){
    var panel = $(elm).next('div.postPanel');  // use next selector 
    if (panel.is(":hidden")) {
       panel.slideDown('slow');
   } else {
     panel.slideUp('slow', function () {
        $(this).hide();
     });
    }
  }
});
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f1yt3vhd/)**

OR

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('div.post').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).next('div.postPanel').slideToggle("slow");
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks but it doesnt work. I tried to click on post, but nothing happens

Comment: @joe pls show your markup code ,without knowing markup we cant solve your problem

Comment: posted example html above.

Comment: many thanks! it works well. next() is essential to get to next panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.siblings()` to find the corresponding `.postPanel` to hide.

You can use `.slideToggle()` to toggle, without writing extra code to check if a `.postPanel` is currently visible.

JS:

```
$('.post').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.postPanel').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owrsjd6q/).

Comment: sorry i tested fiddle but it is not sliding down after a few times click

Comment: @joe There's no reason for it to stop working after a few clicks, so that problem is most likely specifically on your side.